# Use Handbrake to simply fix wrong anamorphic video

Tags: video, video-conversion, handbrake

My Samsung video camera, for some reason I don't know, does not write the correct information for the 16:9 videos. So in order to have the correct aspect ratio, I used to re-encode the video with the correct size: 1024x576. I used to do that with FFMPEG on my Linux box. I wonder if I can use Handbrake (0.9.9) on my Windows 7 (which has a better CPU) in order to do that, but without the need to RE-ENCODE the video, just to rewrite the correct information at the container. Is that possible?

Comment: You will still need to re-encode the video to make sure it has the right aspect ratio flags encoded into the video source, regardless of what video container you use. Handbrake 0.10.0 is out now (available for Windows 7) https://handbrake.fr/  and has a lot of bug fixes with more updated features available. That can fix the aspect ratio. Try using the anamorphic Custom options under the Picture Settings tab in Handbrake, and setup the right display width and PAR. See the following link for handbrake Anamorphic guide: https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/AnamorphicGuide

Comment: Also if you are using the MKV container format, you might be able to use mkvToolnix mkvmerge gui: https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/ .. here is a guide to mkvmerge GUI: https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge-gui.html .. this tool might allow you to change specific flags inside the container regarding aspect ratio, without re-encoding the video.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't said what player you are using. In all probability it is your player that is unable to display the correct aspect ratio. `1024x576` is **not** required. An `Aspect ratio` flag is required. If **however** that flag is missing, (I'm guessing it is not missing) in `ffmpeg` it can be set using `-aspect 16:9`. In Handbrake use a `-p` at the end of the command:

```
./!HandBrakeCLI -i dvd -o movie.mp4 -p
```

In the GUI use the "Strict" parameter in the Anamorphic options.

See [this](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/AnamorphicGuide) for more information.

Comment: No it's not the player is the camera. PAR is missing from the container. Also, -p is not an option in 0.9.9 version. And, finally, that will re-encode the video. I don't want to re-encode the videos.

Comment: Edited my answer a bit.